# R: recursively iterating through parallel ragged lists?

Tags: r, list, recursion, parameters

I have defined a complex parameter hierarchy in the form of a list supplying defaults with attributes defining further characteristics (in the example `several.ok` as used by `match.args`). I now look for a way to merge that list with a partial copy providing customization AND check the result for adherence to attribute-encoded parameters. How to achieve this eludes me (for hours).

Consider the following:

```
defaults_list <- list(
  a = structure('a', several.ok = TRUE),
  b = list(
    b1 = structure('b1', several.ok = TRUE),
    b2 = structure('b2', several.ok = FALSE)))

partial_customization <- list(
  b = list(
    b2 = 'custom_b2'))
```

What I'm looking for is `black_magic` that will achieve:

1. Merge the lists recursively, giving preference to `partial_customization` and
2. Test all resulting elements using the exemplary `several.ok` bool (`FALSE` must be of length 1 - in 'real life' I also have a `class` field to check against etc.)

The result I'm looking for from the above is:

```
result_list <- list(
  a = 'a',
  b = list(
    b1 = 'b1',
    b2 = 'custom_b2')
```

In a case where

```
partial_customization <- list(
  b = list(
    b2 = c('custom_b2.1', 'custom_b2.2')))
```

an error should be thrown as the `several.ok` attribute of `b2` does **not** allow for `length > 1`.

How to do this efficiently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As so often, the solution lies actually in the core set of `R` tools ...
`utils::modifyList` does (nearly) what I am looking for (with respect to merging lists).

As the original function strips attributes I have modified it as follows:

```
modifyList_with_attributes <- function (x, val, keep.null = FALSE, maintain.x.attributes = TRUE)
{
  stopifnot(is.list(x), is.list(val))
  xnames <- names(x)
  vnames <- names(val)
  vnames <- vnames[nzchar(vnames)]
  if (keep.null) {
    for (v in vnames) {
      saved_attributes <- attributes(x[[v]])
      x[v] <- if (v %in% xnames && is.list(x[[v]]) && is.list(val[[v]]))
        list(modifyList_with_attributes(x[[v]], val[[v]], keep.null = keep.null, maintain.x.attributes = maintain.x.attributes))
      else val[v]
      if(maintain.x.attributes)
      {
        attributes(x[[v]]) <- saved_attributes
      }
    }
  }
  else {
    for (v in vnames) {
      saved_attributes <- attributes(x[[v]])
      x[[v]] <- if (v %in% xnames && is.list(x[[v]]) &&
                is.list(val[[v]]))
          modifyList_with_attributes(x[[v]], val[[v]], keep.null = keep.null, maintain.x.attributes = maintain.x.attributes)
        else val[[v]]
      if(maintain.x.attributes)
      {
        attributes(x[[v]]) <- saved_attributes
      }
    }
  }
  x
}
```